# retrieve all words after specific word on the line

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve just Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 from this three lines what is tje code please ? it an array ! i use print_r to get this result

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

the code will search the word server and get all words after that just in the same line

Comment: do a split on "Server:" and then "\n" or use preg_match

Answer (score 3):

If that string is in the variable named $header,

```
preg_match("/^Server: (.*)$/m", $header, $matches);
$server = $matches[1];
```

Should get you the server name

Code if header lines are in an array:

```
$server = NULL;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
{
    // Look in the line for the server header
    $is_match = preg_match("/^Server: (.*)$/", $header[$i], $matches);
    // $is_match holds the number of times our pattern matched (up to 1)
    if ($is_match > 0)
    {
        $server = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to split every lines before doing that.

Comment: @Florent: No, just have to use the [`m` (multi-line) flag](http://ideone.com/fVPp7).

Comment: @Samuel: No worries; I assume you've been in .NET land? (Guessing by how you formatted the pattern). ;-)

Comment: @Samuel oooooooooh it is array error is 

    preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: @MetoMe I updated my answer with a version for if $header is an array

Answer (score 0):

If the `Server: ...` line is always the last line, you can use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).